# How to create a macro string

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I'm trying to define a string macro before compiling my *C* code. I've tried something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%s", AMEM);
    return 0;
}
```

and I've tried to compile with:

```
gcc -D AMEM="Deus Abencoa" file.c
```

But I keep getting this message:

```
file.c:5:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘AMEM’
  printf("%s", AMEM);
               ^
<command-line>:0:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
file.c:5:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘AMEM’
printf("%s", AMEM);
```

Any idea of how to put it to work?

Comment: Note that the space between `-D` and `macro=value` is immaterial; it works with and without that space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell interprets (“eats up”) the double-quotes. Since they need to be part of the cpp macro (as the C compiler requires them to form a string), you must pass them to the compiler driver, which means escaping them from the shell. Try this:

```
gcc -D'AMEM="Deos Abencoa"' file.c
```

Or this (commonly seen with GNU autoconf):

```
gcc -DAMEM=\"Deos\ Abencoa\" file.c
```

Do note that there is no space after `-D` either.

Comment: The space after the `-D` is optional and most often omitted but not necessary.

Comment: What I meant was: note that my (working) way does not have a space. I know systems that require there be no space after cpp options like `-D` and `-I`.

Comment: Which systems require 'no space'?

Comment: I saw GCC choke (on MirBSD, but I think it should also do on GNU/Linux) when the space after `-I` was missing. I cannot state offhead which one it was for `-D` as it's been a very long time since I last accidentally had a space.

Comment: I deleted my comment, as it was off-base. Please adjust your answer to say something like "your shell interprets the double quotes itself and doesn't pass them to gcc".

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc -D AMEM='"Deus Abencoa"' file.c
```

The shell removes the single quotes, leaving the double quotes visible to the compiler. Before, the shell removed the double quotes.